# Head mesh jumps into the eye mesh after joining armatures

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, bones

I joined the armature for eye animation with the armature for the head animation by Ctrl+J. Right after that the head becomes very small rotates 90 degrees and jumps into one of the eyes.

If I hide the head mesh, then the eyes become very big, move above head and overlap.

I managed to partially solve the problem by unparenting meshes from the armatures, then joining the armatures by ctrl+j and then parenting back the eyes. It all worked OK, but I cant parent back the head, as it get deformed in a very strange way.

Comment: Have you applied all transforms before parenting?

Comment: yes,I have applied them, but nothing changed. With the head I applied p. with automatic weights, it gets deformed severely:) I tried to apply p.with envelope groups, the head is no longer deformed, but not affected by the bones either:)

Comment: Hm, hard to say. Can you reproduce the problem? Can you attach an example file?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to look into this issue, Tiles:)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n48Z8paexrqBaNxJR28HsVk0NG-pu4GK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the .blend file. Never mind the eyelids and the mesh, I know it looks awful:)was quickly remaking a rather decently modeled African female of mine. I am learning animation of humans, this is my first project:)

Comment: I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI6DvQTdvBU&t=2362s

Comment: I have tried to do the same thing i guess about 25 times:) I have tried this method for joining armatures in 4 different files . modelling simple meshes from scratch. yet the eyes become big and jump into each other after joining those armatures:)

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the file. This is caused by your shapekeys that uses vertex groups. Weighting is also assigning vertex groups. And that's what is conflicting here when you skin your headmesh. When i remove the vertex groups for the shapekeys before skinning then all works well.

So, first skin the head mesh, then create the shape keys for it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention:) I thought about shape keys, that's why I created totally new files with simplistic turtle-like meshes, just head and the eyes:) no shape keys, nothing at all:) Maybe I have activated something which shouldn't be activated, maybe in the user settings... I don't know:) Will upload the experimental turtle file in a minute:)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KuW6jI8r5i3UB4IhaazF8RJc9AgpU9QC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have just tried deleting the shape keys, It didn't work for me, again the eyes become bigger than head and jump into each other just like in the turtle file:) This is giving me grey hairs:) Could you please have a look at that turtle file?:)

Comment: You need to remove the vertex groups, not just the shape keys.

Comment: it didn't work for me. I have removed them too, before writing  the previous comment. I have come across a similar problem here, the solution was to slightly bend the armature before parenting (a bit different case), but I tried  bending the head armature, and the eyes haven't become big and jumped into each other, but remained their original size and jumped opposite to each other and sit on the ends of the biggest bone:)

Comment: I know it worked for you, which makes me think that something is wrong with my I don;t do settings maybe, or maybe something very very obvious I am doing wrong:)Because the new "turtle" file had the same problem:)

Comment: Thanks again for all the time and your spirit of investigation:)

Comment: :) I am still experimenting with the turtle file. I have some progress, but the result is not what I expect. After joining the armatures I got the deformed eyes I unparented them they became normal and then parented them again. Everything looks fine at this stage which is quite unexpected, but then when I want to attach the eye bones to the head bone and to the neck bone they head mesh becomes quite bent though it's is not that terrible I can almost achieve a decent result by moving the head bone in edit mode, then it looks 95% OK:) but when I am starting to "move" the eyes it gets mad

Comment: I have solved it for both files. It seems like the problem was in naming, or rather unnaming bones:) I also recalculated normals. By the way, it worked for the file with the shape keys:)Luckily, I didn't have to delete them:)

Answer (score 0):

After joining armatures bones matrices are rewritten relative to new armature and every child object or paint weighted object goes to its local coordinates. So the cleanest way is that first you remove any parenting or weight paint from joining armature and after joining redo skinning and parenting.